# Tensorflow handling arrays as feature_columns

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a classifier which takes an array of floats as an input.

Despite following steps [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/estimators/linear) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/numeric_column) to include an array as the input feature I keep getting an TypeError whereby the estimator doesn't recognise the shape of the input.

How do you include an array as a feature for an estimator? Can you simply pass in the numeric_column with an appropriate shape as expected in the docs?

Sample code here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import feature_column

z = [[1, 2], [3,4]]
df = pd.DataFrame(z)
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.array(x), axis=1)

feature_columns = []

for col in ['feature']:
    feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(col, shape=(2, )))

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.columns = ['feature']
df['target'] = 1
y_train = df.pop('target')

def make_input_fn(X, y, n_epochs=None, shuffle=True):
    def input_fn():
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(X), y))
        if shuffle:
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(20)
        # For training, cycle thru dataset as many times as need (n_epochs=None).    
        dataset = dataset.repeat(n_epochs)  
        # In memory training doesn't use batching.
        dataset = dataset.batch(5)
        return dataset
    return input_fn

train_input_fn = make_input_fn(df, y_train)

linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns)

linear_est.train(train_input_fn, max_steps=100)
```

which gives a stack trace of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<string>", line 39, in <module>
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 359, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1139, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1166, in _train_model_default
    input_fn, ModeKeys.TRAIN))
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1003, in _get_features_and_labels_from_input_fn
    self._call_input_fn(input_fn, mode))
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1094, in _call_input_fn
    return input_fn(**kwargs)
  File "<string>", line 23, in input_fn
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 279, in from_tensor_slices
    return TensorSliceDataset(tensors)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2091, in __init__
    for i, t in enumerate(nest.flatten(tensors))
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2091, in <listcomp>
    for i, t in enumerate(nest.flatten(tensors))
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1050, in convert_to_tensor
    return convert_to_tensor_v2(value, dtype, preferred_dtype, name)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1108, in convert_to_tensor_v2
    as_ref=False)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1186, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 304, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 245, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 283, in _constant_impl
    allow_broadcast=allow_broadcast))
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 574, in make_tensor_proto
    append_fn(tensor_proto, proto_values)
  File "tensorflow/python/framework/fast_tensor_util.pyx", line 127, in tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util.AppendObjectArrayToTensorProto
  File "/Users/nicholashilton/.virtualenvs/fantifi/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 61, in as_bytes
    (bytes_or_text,))
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got array([1, 2])
```